# Fetch week numbers with date range of each week for a whole year

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date-range, week-number

Using SQL Server, I need to fetch the date ranges for every week by week number for a whole year. The first day of week needs to be Monday, unless the week starts in another year, then I need it to start at the first day of the year.

For Example,

if I call the select with the year 2021 as the parameter, I would like the output to be something like that :

```
WeekNumbers:      DateStart:        DateEnd:
1                 2021-01-01        2021-01-03
2                 2021-01-04        2021-01-10
...
...
52                2021-12-20        2021-12-26
53                2021-12-27        2021-12-31
```

Please notice the first and the last week number of the year of the example.

Thanks

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42794544/get-week-number-in-year-from-date) will help

Comment: Look at this answer here.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/41400006/14737464   You should be able to work your problem out from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to solve this problem.  A brute force approach generates all the dates using a some method -- this uses a recursive CTE -- and then assigns the weeks based on a window function counting the Mondays.

```
with cte as (
      select datefromparts(2021, 1, 1) as dte
      union all
      select dateadd(day, 1, dte)
      from cte
      where dte < datefromparts(2021, 12, 31)
     )
select weeknum, min(dte), max(dte)
from (select cte.*,
             sum(case when datename(weekday, dte) = 'Monday' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by dte) as weeknum
      from cte
     ) cte
group by weeknum
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

This is fine for a one-off query, but isn't the most efficient method to generate the weeks.  It is, however, a fun illustration of recursive CTEs.  That said, you should probably really have a calendar table of some sort that encapsulates this information *as a table*.

Comment: I only have a single question, when the Monday happens to be the first day of the week, the week number starts at 0, Do You know how I could change that ? 

Thanks

Comment: @MadBrother33 . . . When Monday is the first day of the *year*, then the week number starts at 1:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9029907c028895b754625c8c955274cb.

Comment: Yeah I figured it out, Thanks for everything :)